# Sources on S4 objects, methods and programming in R

Tags: r, reference, manual, r-s4

As I'm often confronted with situations where S4 programming is needed to keep an overview, I've collected quite some sources on S4 objects, methods and programming. I've listed them here as a reference. Please add your own sources as well.

**On the web**

- [The `methods` help files](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/Methods.html) : help files from the package methods, where much of the necessary information can be found
- [S4 classes in 15 pages](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/S-Workshop/Gentleman/S4Objects.pdf) : Short introduction on the programming with S4 objects.
- [How S4 methods work](http://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf) : more explanation about the underlying mechanisms.
- [Not so short introduction to S4](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf) : with practical examples of how to construct the classes and some useful tips. It contains a handy overview as appendix, but contains errors as well. Care should be taken using this one.
- [OOP in R](http://www.math.ku.dk/~richard/courses/bioconductor2009/handout/17_08_Monday/OOP-handouts.pdf) : handout notes with practical examples on S3 and S4
- [S4 Objects](http://www.soph.uab.edu/Statgenetics/Events/Rshort/060227-8-s4slides.pdf) : presentation by Thomas Lumley about S4 objects.
- [R object oriented programming](https://github.com/lgatto/roo)  : in-depth introduction to object oriented programming in R. It covers S3, S4 and S4 reference classes. The accompanying [sequences](https://github.com/lgatto/sequences/) package implements the class system used throughout the slides.

**Books**

- Software for Data Analysis-Programming with R (J. Chambers) : A classic, although not reviewed positive everywhere, that contains a large section on S4
- R programming for Bioinformatics (R. Gentleman) : specifically directed towards working with Bioconductor, which is completely based on S4. But it gives a broad overview and is useful for many other people too.

PS : if somebody finds the community checkbox, you can make this a community-owned post. Somehow I can't find it in the edit window any more...

Comment: How about adding the links to help topics in methods package directly? There are just a few of them, and is useful for quick reference. By the way "Not so short introduction to s4" has a memo at the end which is worth pointing out in my opinion. I am ussing it as refcard.

Comment: Community wiki is now available to user with [at least 10.000 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741). So ask Dirk or Shane on chat ;)

Comment: I would not recommend the "not so short introduction to S4" - it unfortunately contains a large number of errors.

Comment: @Marek: If enough of us edit it it will also become community wiki automatically.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My write up of S4 (still in progress) is available here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html

Answer (score 4):

[R for programmers](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/R/RProg.pdf) (Matloff) (free) and [Introduction to scientific programming and simulation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420068725) (Jones) have a short section on "new-style" S4 classes.

Answer (score 2):

Another good book by John Chambers: "Programming with Data: A Guide to the S Language". As the name suggests it is actually about S, not R, but it provides a lot of valuable information about S4 classes anyway.

There's also some information in the R manuals "Writing R Extensions" and "R Internals" (particularly the latter). Those can be found at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/.

Finally, I would recommend ["How S4 Methods Work"](http://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf), which is a great overview of how to think about S4 as it fits into R.