# $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: r, data-analysis, text-analysis

I have been working on working on applying top.topic.words function and I have got this error.Would anyone be able to help me out with this?.

`> top.words <- top.topic.words(l$V1, 5, by.score=TRUE)
Error in l$V1 : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Comment: It depends on what you have created as the object `l`. Try `class(l)` and see what you get. Does `l$V1` work as a standalone command? (I expect not)

Comment: I am a newbie in both R and text analysis. Having a tough time.
This is what I am getting:
> class(l) [1] "LDA_Gibbs" attr(,"package") [1] "topicmodels"

Comment: Right — you can only use `$` with `data.frame` objects and similar. Consult the help pages for `LDA_Gibbs` and `topicmodels` for how to extract the `V1` element of this object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helping out. Will go through it and try to figure out. :)

Comment: `l@V1` - hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713968/r-what-are-slots