# Why is it not recommended to use multiple inheritance?

Tags: r, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, r-s4

I am creating S4 classes in R.

I read in https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4

> Note that S4 supports multiple inheritance, but this should be used
>   with extreme caution as it makes method lookup extremely complicated.

What is method lookup and why is it more complex with multiple inheritance?

Comment: Just making sure you're aware of the numerous S4 resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143611/sources-on-s4-objects-methods-and-programming-in-r

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you type `f(x)`, with `x` belonging to several classes (say, A, B and C), the computer has to decide which `f` method to call (that from class A, B, or C): this is called "method lookup".

Multiple inheritance often poses problems when the code evolves.

Imagine you have written two base classes A and B, and class C inherits from both. Everything works fine.
A few months later, a developer, who uses class A, and is completely unaware of classes B and C (he does not need them), adds a new method to class A. Unbeknownst to him, there is already a method with the same name in class B. What happens to objects of class C? Will the method from A or B be used? In some languages, the code may fail, in others you can have an undefined behaviour and a very hard-to-catch bug.

Comment: I think your explanation is a bit confused about s4 methods - they belong to functions, not classes.